# Reset Code-Review score on Gerrit when a new patch set is submit

Tags: gerrit

When I rejected a patch set on Gerrit, the score is set for example to `-2`. After that, the developer makes some changes leading to a new patch set on Gerrit.

**The Code-Review score is not reset when a new patch set is pushed**.

I would like to reset the score to easily know which changes are available to look for. Otherwise, I don't know which patch are ready to read again or not.

I looked the [documentation there](http://gerrit-documentation.storage.googleapis.com/Documentation/2.11/config-labels.html#label_copyAllScoresIfNoCodeChange) but I don't see what I am looking for.

**Is there a way to reset Code-review score without changing the code ?**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to set the following in the project.config file on refs/meta/config branch in All-Projects project:

```
[label "Code-Review"]
    copyMinScore = false
    ...
```

You can do this using the GUI at: Projects > List > All-Projects > General > Edit Config

More info at: https://gerrit-review.googlesource.com/Documentation/config-labels.html#label_copyMinScore